# Getting the time when the file was committed on Github

Tags: git, github, github-api, gitpython, pygithub

I want to somehow want to see if there is a way to get the **time** for when a `file was committed` on Github. I have tried using `PyGithub` and `GitPython`, but they don't have any options as such. Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: "committed on github" makes no sense. Do you mean pushed to github? Or committed locally?

Comment: pushed to github. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

you can check the hour in the `log`

so do `git log` to check all commits hours.

but if you want an specific file, you should use the flag `--follow`

so try this:

`git log --follow filename`

### another aproach

if you want just to check the date of an specific commit use this command

`git show -s --format=%ci <commit>`

### Pythonic way

```
import git 
g = git.Git("/path/to/your/repo") 
loginfo = g.log()
print loginfo
```

or

```
import git 
g = git.Git("/path/to/your/repo") 
loginfo = g.log('--format=%ci <commit>')
print loginfo
```

Comment: is there a Pythonic way to do it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciated :)

Comment: Done, sure. is there any way to get the `file` associated with each commit as well?

Comment: to get file use: `g.log('--', "YOUR_FILE_NAME.FILE_EXTENSION")`